# what is data-view attribute in Durandal JS

Tags: javascript, html, durandal

I am playing around with durandal js starter kit application, and at some point when I viewed the source of the page in Mozilla browser, I saw something as follows.

```
<div class="" data-view="views/shell" style="" data-active-view="true"> </div>
```

I can't find anywhere, what the `data-view` attribute does. Is this a custom attribute used by durandal js, or by any other javascript library or by html itself?

Comment: Could you please share the code you were looking at? As far as I can tell there's nothing on the Durandal docs about this `data-view` attribute.

Comment: http://durandaljs.com/version/latest/HTML%20StarterKit.zip

Comment: visit the flickr tab and view the source of the page

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer to your question is this:
That attribute allows Durandal to keep track of where, relative to the `root` directory of the application are views located.
`data-view="views/shell"` basically lets Durandal know that the `shell.html` template(view) is located in the `views/` directory, and whenever something triggers a full application refresh, Durandal knows where to pull this exact view. The `shell` view basically means the outer shell of the web application.
Here are the logs when reloading the application/clicking on the Flickr tab:

```
Debug:Enabled
Application:Starting
Plugin:Installed plugins/router
Plugin:Installed plugins/dialog
Application:Started
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8000/app/views/shell.html".
Navigation Complete ctor {displayName: "Welcome to the Durandal Starter Kit!", description: "Durandal is a cross-device, cross-platform client … Applications (SPAs) easy to create and maintain.", features: Array[11], __moduleId__: "viewmodels/welcome"} Object {fragment: "", queryString: null, config: Object, params: Array[0], queryParams: null}
Binding views/shell Object {router: Object, search: function, activate: function, __moduleId__: "viewmodels/shell"}
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8000/app/views/welcome.html".
Using CSS3 animations.
Binding views/welcome ctor {displayName: "Welcome to the Durandal Starter Kit!", description: "Durandal is a cross-device, cross-platform client … Applications (SPAs) easy to create and maintain.", features: Array[11], __moduleId__: "viewmodels/welcome"}
```

See those "XHR finished loading" messages? That's where Durandal is loading the views by fetching their paths from `data-view` attributes.

Clicking on the "Flickr" tab gives us the following:

```
Activating Object {displayName: "Flickr", images: function, activate: function, select: function, canDeactivate: function…}
Navigation Complete Object {displayName: "Flickr", images: function, activate: function, select: function, canDeactivate: function…} Object {fragment: "flickr", queryString: null, config: Object, params: Array[0], queryParams: null}
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8000/app/views/flickr.html".
Binding views/flickr Object {displayName: "Flickr", images: function, activate: function, select: function, canDeactivate: function…}
```

See, "XHR finished loading ...views/flickr.html" -- the `data-view` attribute being queried again for view path and the view being retrieved via AJAX.

Hope this clears things out for you.

Comment: Okay..but why wasn't that documented anywhere?

Comment: This question can be geared towards the Durandal dev team. Maybe you should tweet at them, I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Comment: Could also come from KnockoutJS as I know that Durandal is using Knockout for a lot of stuff.

Comment: The answer is right but i donot think it is coming from ko. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp shows you more about data-* tags. I think durandal used this to specify the location of the view.

Comment: Yes @BudsNanKis, that was exactly what I said in my answer: _That attribute allows Durandal to keep track of where, relative to the root directory of the application are views located . _
I tend to advise against using W3Schools. Even though years ago I used to check out their examples, as there wasn't that much information on the web for a self-taught, beginner programmer like myself, I realised over the years that they have a lot of poor examples and hated their former strategy of claiming they're associated with the W3C. Try Pluralsight,TutsPlus,MDN,WHATWG.